# Is it possible to READ LOCK all databases and then UNLOCK one by one?

Tags: mysql, replication, locking

I need to take backup of databases from a live server for replication. There could be 2-5 databases each having size of 1-5 GB. Master is a live server so I can not stop mysql service. Since size of data is big, baking up in Read-Only mode could be dangerous too. I'm wondering is it possible to

**1. READ LOCK all databases and stop bin-log writing**
**2. Take backup of a database and UNLOCK only that one.**

MySQL Version   : 5.1.61
Storage Engine  : MyISAM

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Percona's Open Source and free XtraBackup to perform hot backups!

Comment: @ Vérace thanks for answering but I don't want to use any other tool. Just want to if this is possible.

Comment: So, you're taking backups from the replicated intances, not the server? It seems to me that your data is, in fact, quite small - you could easily take hot backups from the master using XtraBackup (and/or from the replicas!).

Comment: @ Vérace Sorry, my question was not clear enough, I'm taking backup of all databases from MASTER and the size of data is huge.  I couldn't understand what you meant by **replicated intances** and why do you think data is 'quite small'?
 
Replication is not created yet or it's broken and the data is unusable.
Again, I'm not looking for any other tool. Just want to know if it's possible and safe. Though the idea seems insane to myself too.

Comment: 1 - 5 GB is not very big these days. Unless you have specific windows where can shut down MySQL, you'll want a hot backup solution. Do you have Enterprise MySQL? I thought you had a replication setup, and wanted to backup off that.

Comment: 5.1 - Ugh.  MyISAM - Ugh.  Backing up one database at a time and expecting consistency - Ugh.

Comment: XtraBackup cannot hot-backup MyISAM tables, only InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you *already* have a Slave hanging off the Master, `STOP SLAVE` and backup the Slave.

If you are trying to set up replication to begin with, you are out of luck because you are still on MyISAM.